# AES secret key lost on application start

Tags: java, encryption, aes

I am using AES encryption and have encrypted a message with a key generated from key generator. Encryption and Decryption is working as expected.
But when the application is restarted and I am trying to decrypt the same message again, it is giving error as the secret key is not stored anywhere which was used to encrypt the message and on restart of application we don't have that secret key anymore.

Cannot invoke javax.crypto.Cipher.getIV() because AES.encryptionCipher is null.

I don't want to store the secret key in database. Can I store the secretKey and write it in a file and place that file in src/main/resources folder.Will it be a good approach?

Is there any other place where I could store the secret key and at the time of decrypting the meesages I could load the key from that place and decrypt messages.

This is what I have done so far.

```
private static SecretKey key;
private static int KEY_SIZE = 128;
private static int T_LEN = 128;
private static Cipher encryptionCipher;


public static String encrypt(String message) {
    byte[] messageInBytes = message.getBytes();
    byte[] encryptedBytes = null;
    try {
        KeyGenerator generator = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");       
        generator.init(KEY_SIZE);
        key = generator.generateKey();
        encryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        encryptionCipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        encryptedBytes = encryptionCipher.doFinal(messageInBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return encode(encryptedBytes);

}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedMessage) {
    byte[] messageInBytes = decode(encryptedMessage);
    byte[] decryptedBytes = null;
    try {
        Cipher decryptionCipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/GCM/NoPadding");
        GCMParameterSpec spec = new GCMParameterSpec(T_LEN, encryptionCipher.getIV());
        decryptionCipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, spec);
        decryptedBytes = decryptionCipher.doFinal(messageInBytes);
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException | InvalidAlgorithmParameterException | NoSuchPaddingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException | BadPaddingException | InvalidKeyException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return new String(decryptedBytes);

}

private static String encode(byte[] data) {
    return Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(data);
}


private static byte[] decode(String data) {
    return Base64.getDecoder().decode(data);
}
```

Comment: *I don't want to store the secret key in database. Can I store the secretKey and write it in a file and place that file in src/main/resources folder.Will it be a good approach?* Obviously not. Storing keys unless they are highly protected is an obvious no-no. This is why symmetric encryption is not easy. Why are you not using public/private keys?

Comment: Our team wants to go for AES encryption.

Comment: Can you please help me on how to proceed forward in storing key with my current implementation.

Comment: Encryption implemented badly will give you a very false sense of security. You might find out the hard way that the security you think you've got is an illusion

Comment: In that case what would you suggest,should i not use AES encryption and go for some other encryption.And if that's the case what should i use.

Comment: I need to know your use case in detail to be able to say anything about that

Comment: I have encrypted a token in my java application and I have sent that token back to react application and now my react client would call APIs in my backend server with that token My backend will decrypt the token with that secret key.

Comment: Sanity v. Security. If you are using symmetric encryption, the key needs to live somewhere. It's not necessarily a bad thing to store the key on the machine performing the encryption/decryption, but you'll need to ensure the proper access controls are implemented. If it suits your needs, you could still do something like RSA encrypt the AES key, but since the RSA private key will also need to live somewhere, you will have the same issue. Carefully consider where your keys should live and go from there.

Comment: @hr0r53 thats what my concern is where actually in my java application should i put my key ??can i put it in a file in resources folder or somewhere else.I am a little not sure on this thing.

Comment: You can put it in resources, sure, or anywhere on your file system. Just understand that anyone with access to the filesystem may be able to access the AES secret key, and thus they could encrypt/decrypt the data your app is operating on. Ask yourself this - "Am I concerned with the potential for an unauthorized person accessing the AES key on the machine's filesystem?" If no, then store the key in your app resources and ensure it is not included in version control. If yes, then either consider asymmetric cryptography or whether or not encrypting your data actually achieves security.

Comment: Okay I don’t have much knowledge on asymmetric encryption .What encryption can we use for asymmetric cryptography and even in that case we have to store private key somewhere right

Comment: Is this app just for your use or is your app going to be distributed for others to use?

Comment: It’s going to be distributed for others use.it’s a company’s mobile app for employees

Comment: If this is for a mobile app, then I imagine you have some web server backend. You can store the private key on the backend and ship the public key with the app. Then, app users will be able to encrypt data and only the backend will be able to decrypt it. App users can also verify the integrity of backend data by validating cryptographic signatures with the public key. What you probably shouldn't do is ship a shared AES key with the app.

Comment: I don't know what data you are attempting to encrypt, but it's also worth asking "should this data be encrypted in the first place?" If yes, then what security are you providing by using symmetric encryption? If you encrypt data but give everyone access to the key, then you haven't really secured anything.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar situation, still have some open part. Suggested solution solve some, but still there are some open question, hopefully we can have common approach with expert inputs.

Keytool to generate Secret Key

```
keytool -genseckey  -alias aeskey -keyalg AES -keysize 128  -keypass password -keystore project.keystore -storetype pkcs12
```

refer the Oracle [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/specs/man/keytool.html#commands-and-options) for details.

- Java provide standard Java keystore(JKS), Secret key can be stored in jks file before starting application and this file can be read again on restart.
- JKS also need password to access, in this approach, challenge is how to keep java keystore password securely
- my suggestion is keystore password can be saved securely in new  platform like kubernetes ( any other suggestion?)

Reference source  code to retrieve Secret Key from Java Keystore:

```
    KeyStore ks = KeyStore.getInstance("pkcs12");
    String keyStorePassword = appSecurityConfig.getJksPass(); //get keystore password from external configuration, like kubernetes secret
       //appSecurityConfig is configuration class
    char [] password = keyStorePassword.toCharArray();

    ks.load(new FileInputStream(appSecurityConfig.getKeystoreFile()), password);    //keystoreFile -> JKS file name
    
    SecretKey secretKey = (SecretKey) ks.getKey("kskey", password); //kskey -> is secreykey alias
```

Comment: Ok and where do we have this key store file created and where can I load this from .My application is hosted on azure platform.In that case where does this file gets created on azure server?

Comment: added command to generate securekey. <project>.keystore file can be store in server configuration directory. for example ${HOME}/config

Comment: SecretKey entries can NOT be stored in JKS files, but can in JCEKS and PKCS12; you used the latter. (Other keystore providers vary, and aren't portable.) Although you didn't say so, you linked to Java 13 doc, and inJava  versions 9 up `keytool` defaults to PKCS12 (and so does the API although you didn't use that default), but they still support JKS if you explicitly specify it and then `-genseckey` fails.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 java keystore has different format, secretKey is  not supported in JKS but in PKCS12 , this is one of format.  PKCS12 enhanced  the compatibility across platform.  The shared command doesn't gave error, let me know if there is any error.  i still didnt get you what is your suggestion. are you not recommending java keystore? looking for alternative solution too.

Comment: In j9+ your command works, but it doesn't use JKS as your text states. If you _specify_ JKS, or use j8 or lower where JKS is the default, it does _not_ work. I do support using PKCS12 for Java keystores (for both compatibility _and_ security). I don't take a position in general on using (any type of) keystore for symmetric keys, but I agree it is an option; the requirements here are far too vague for me to design alternatives.

Comment: Requirement is like this where my front end react application is calling a token api in java backend which returns a json object which has a token attribute ,I need to encrypt the value of that token in my Java backend and send the encrypted value of token attribute in the json object to react .Now when ever the react application makes calls to my other apis ,I need to decrypt that token first ,check if it’s valid and then process the request .I wanted to achieve the encryption using AES .Is there a better way then please suggest